# question about the tightness of probability measures for a general topological space

Tags: pr.probability, gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{X})$ be a topological space and denote by $\mathcal{F}$ its collection of Borel subsets referred to $\mathcal{X}$. Now let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of all probabilities on $(E,\mathcal{F})$ and suppose the subset $\mathcal{M}\subset\mathcal{P}$ is tight.

My question is whether $\mathcal{M}$ is relatively compact with respect to weak-${\ast}$ convergence, that is to say, for any sequence $\{P_n\}\subset\mathcal{M}$, we can find a convergent subsequence $\{P_{n_k}\}$, i.e. there exists some $P\in\mathcal{P}$ such that for every $\mathcal{X}$-continuous and bounded function $f$ one has

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{E} fdP_{n_k}=\int_{E} fdP$$

Thx for the reply!

Comment: In very general and reasonable assumptions regarding the topology (Polish space is probably more than enough) this is the contents of Prokhorov's theorem.

Comment: "Polish" means separable and complete, but not necessarily a metric space I suppose

Comment: In fact according to Chapter I of Billingsley <<Convergence of probability>>, $E$ is alway assumed to be a metric space.

Comment: Well, you're only asking about half of Prokhorov's theorem (namely, tight implies rel. compact).  

This is probably true in every space which can be exhausted by compacts + able to apply Urysohn's lemma or something (to get $C_c$ approx. to the compacts). 

Probably whenever you can use the Riesz' rep. theorem to construct measure, this half of Prokhorov's  theorem will work as well, but you should consult the literature, Billingsley's book is a good reference.

Comment: You should carefully distinguish (relative) compactness and sequential compactness.

Comment: Bogachev's Measure Theory volume 2 is a good source for results like this in their most general form, and Theorem 8.6.7 addresses this question for completely regular spaces.